# Ajax/jQuery Dynamic Dependent Dropdowns with PHP/mySQL - Dropdowns reset but not repopulating after cloning table rows

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, dropdown, clone

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Working on a table that will allow users to enter multiple items/rows on a purchase order to then be insert into a mySQL database. Dynamic dropdowns work on the first row and clear back to "" on additional rows once a new row is added/cloned, but the dynamic dropdown lists (columns 2-4 for Type, Category, and Subcategory) only include the dynamically populated options from Row 1 (if any were selected) for the Category and Subcategory columns, even when the Type dropdown is changed.

For example, on Row 2, once the "Type" is set to "Electronic" it should only have 2 options: "Laptop" or "Mobile."

I've tried setting a variable to create an array of values for each typeid selected, but that breaks it.

Table:

```
              <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
                <table id="poList" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th data-orderable="false">#</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Type</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Category</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Subcategory</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Item Name</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Inclusions</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Condition</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false">Value</th>
                      <th data-orderable="false"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="bottomtbody">
                    <tr id='tmp'>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="typeid" id="typeid" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php echo $inventory->typeDropdownList();?>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="categoryid" id="categoryid" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="brandid" id="brandid" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="itemName" id="itemName" class="form-control" required />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="inclusionid" id="inclusionid" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php echo $inventory->inclusionDropdownList();?>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="inclusionid" id="inclusionid" class="form-control" required>
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php echo $inventory->conditionDropdownList();?>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="total_value" id="total_value" class="form-control" required pattern="[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+" />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type='delete' id='deleteRow' class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">X</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div align='right'>
                  <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Submit</button>
                </div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#typeid', function() {
    var typeid = $('#typeid').val();
    var btn_action = 'getTypeCategory';
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        typeid: typeid,
        btn_action: btn_action
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#categoryid').html(data);
        var categoryid = $('#categoryid').val();
        var btn_action = 'getCategoryBrand';
        $.ajax({
          url: "action.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            categoryid: categoryid,
            btn_action: btn_action
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#brandid').html(data);
            productData.ajax.reload();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'input#tmpAddRow', function($e) {
    $e.preventDefault();
    $('tr#tmp').clone(true).removeAttr('id').find('input,select').val('').end().appendTo('#bottomtbody');
  });
  $('tr input[type=text]').focus(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('myFocused');
    }
  ).blur(
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('myFocused');
    });
});
```

**** UPDATE #1 ****

Changed to using Class instead of ID, set variables to repopulate for different values on each row, and change to on-click instead on-change. Dropdowns are now populating correctly, but when the Category and Subcategory dropdowns are changed they change for ALL rows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.typeid', function() {
    var typeid = $(this).val();
    var btn_action = 'getTypeCategory';
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        typeid: typeid,
        btn_action: btn_action
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.categoryid').html(data);
        $('.brandid').html("");
        productData.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.categoryid', function() {
    var categoryid = $(this).val();
    var btn_action = 'getCategoryBrand';
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        categoryid: categoryid,
        btn_action: btn_action
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.brandid').html(data);
        productData.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
  });
```